# what do the default set of resource actions return in angular and how can I modify the returned asset?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've given an example code below and I want to add an element to the users array. When I console log the users object I'm getting an array with 1 element but it has 3 resource objects, a promise and a $resolved property. Can someone explain what I'm missing here.

```
 /*@ngInject*/
    constructor(User, Auth, $state, $uibModal, $scope) {
      this.Auth = Auth;
      this.$state = $state;
      this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
      this.$scope = $scope;

      this.newUser = {name: "New User", email: "newUser@gmail.com", password: "gg"};
      this.users = User.query();
      this.users.push(this.newUser);
      console.log(this.users);

      this.$scope.$watch('this.user', function(newUser) {
        console.log("entered watch");
        var val = this.users.indexOf(newUser);
        if(val == this.users.length - 1 ) {
          this.openNewUser();
        }
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you're missing is the fact that the call to `User.query()` is asynchronous, meaning the returned value is populated at a later time.

You'll need to attach a callback to the query's promise (`this.users.$promise`) if you want to execute code that is dependent on `this.users`

Example:

```
//First get the users
var self = this;
this.users = User.query();
this.users.$promise.then(function(){
 //Do stuff with the user list
 self.users.push(this.newUser);
});
```

Comment: I tried to do it inside the success function as you've shown but it says that 'this' of 'this.users.push()' is undefined inside it. What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Actually I want it in es6 but I got the scope issue with your previous way. I'm trying to fix it but I don't think I understand the issue with the scope.